# Op Amps and High Pass Filters; Low Audio Volume

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, frequency, automotive, active-filter

I'm working on an audio crossover for a friend's stereo system. I have a passive design that uses a single 330uF in series with the positive audio line. It works like a charm , but I'd like to see if I can pull off an active filter instead.

I have a MAX410, MAX492, TLC7111 (which so far has produced the worst quality), as well as an ADA4895-1 (which I'm working on putting on a board to test). So far the MAX410 has produced the best results and sound (which is what I have currently hooked up). But with one issue....

It seems the volume is about 1\16th that of the input signal. I have tried at least a half dozen schematics\configurations with the same results. And this is a big problem as I need the input and output signals to match volume. But it's seeming like this may not be possible

Here is my schematic. VCC is +5V, R2, 3, and 4 are 10k (with the exception of R1 which is 1k), and C1\C2 are 0.1u:

[image: High Pass Op Amp Schematic]

And here is a picture of my breadboard using the MAX410 (*Ignore the board in the upper left corner. It's NOT being used or at all active*):

[image]

I have also tried running the op amp with both a regular ground as well as a virtual ground by using a 1k voltage divider; same result of the output being too quiet.

The output is to speakers. Currently I'm using headphones with a 23 ohm impedance. His system is a 4 ohm impedance.

EDIT: Please ask for any information that you need on top of the information I have provided. I have given everything that I currently have.

Comment: excuse me but a crossover in my mind has one input and two outputs, a topology that is quite difficult to achieve with a single capacitor. would you include your current circuit in the question?

Comment: Are you sure you've got your inverting input (pin 2) correctly connected? It looks like the orange wire is going from pin 2 to row 10 near-side, but the pair of resistors is on row 11.

Comment: There are two capacitors in the schematic and picture

Comment: And that circuit needs either a good virtual ground or a split-supply.

Comment: What are you feeding the op-amp output into? What are your op-amp supply voltages? Also, please show your exact circuit diagram not some cut and paste from the web.

Comment: brhans, I have a virtual ground, and it produces the same result as a normal ground, as stated above. Andy aka, hat s my exact diagram. And I provided values above. The output is going to a headphone jack (in the picture, blue wire). VCC is +5V

Comment: What's the load on the op-amp i.e. what is connected to the jack and what impedance is it? Please don't BS me if you want my help - THAT IS NOT THE EXACT CIRCUIT DIAGRAM - I see regulators and supply decouplers and THAT circuit WILL NOT run from a single 5V supply.

Comment: A pair of headphones... Apple Earpods, so they have a 23 ohm impedance. I tried with a pair of KRK KNS8400's as well, they have a 32 ohm impedance.

Comment: @Dominic, what brhans means by a "good virtual ground" is a virtual ground with low output impedance. Your 1k divider has a 500 ohm output impedance; you should buffer it (with an op-amp buffer).

Comment: I'd be happy to do that, but wouldn't that require that I have a split supply for the buffer as well? Andy aka, please read all the way through my post. I specifically stated that regulator in the top left corner was to be disregarded as it is NOT connected. And I believe I said I had tried a divider with no luck. But there is one on there, just not in use. As far as a decoupler, it's a decoupler..... 0.1uF...

Comment: So we have an ambiguous picture, schematic with no component values, mention of components that seem to have nothing to do with said schematic, and a chain of comments that adds more confusion. This is a mess, voting to close until it's fixed.

Comment: How is this a mess? I provided as much information here as I have provided in the past with absolutely no issues or argument from anyone whatsoever. Everything I have provided is relevant to what I'm doing. And if anyone needs any other information, I'm happy to provide it and edit the initial post accordingly.

Comment: I think the biggest confusion is about the application of your circuit. You say that the passive filter is a single 330 uF capacitor, which suggests that it is connected to a low-impedance load, such as directly to a speaker connected to the *output* of a power amplifier. On the other hand, the active filter circuit you're asking about is opamp-based, and would normally be used in a line-level filter, at the *input* to the power amplifier. Such a system is called "bi-amplification", where each frequency band has a dedicated power amp. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Please, re-read the first paragraph. I stated that ALTHOUGH I have made a simple high pass filter with a 330uF cap, I'm trying to make an active filter INSTEAD. And as stated also in the first paragraph, it's for a friend's stereo system. The stereo system is for his truck. I'm trying to create a high pass at 120Hz

Answer (score 3):

The MAX410 will not drive headphones (23 ohms or 32 ohms) as you expect - it's just an op-amp (not some small power amp) and might be expected to deliver a 2.3Vp-p output signal into a 2kohm load. It's got a short circuit current of 35mA so, you might get 20mA peaks with an output voltage of maybe 2Vp-p. That's a power of about 25 milli watts.

Also, the schematic as shown in your question will not work from a single 5V supply - you need a voltage midpoint to reference your input and output signal against. As it stands your output will be pityfully low and probably show signs of being half wave rectified against the 0V (most negative) rail.

Read the data sheet and please also provide a proper "full" circuit diagram if you are interested in other questions being answered.

---

EDIT section following disclosure by OP of a resistor value change.

Changing R1 to 1k from 10k will also not achieve what you want (irrespective of other errors). This will produce a gain of about 11 and when you say: -

> I need the input and output signals to match volume

This contradicts R1 being 1k. In fact, with it at 10k you will have a pass-band gain of 2 so this might be another issue you wish to consider. Try removing R1 and splitting R3 into two resistors (20k each) to both supply rails.

Answer (score 2):

Something seems wrong to me - you mention that you are currently using a 330 uF capacitor.

What is the impedance of your load?  Are you expecting to feed something like a speaker or headphones with this or is it feeding an amplifier?

For example, many audio amplifier inputs have an input impedance of 10 KOhms.  Your 330 uF capacitor would give you a high-pass filter with a break point of about 0.048 Hz.  So you obviously can't be working with a high impedance (10K) input.

That means that you may be trying to have your filter directly drive your load.  That isn't a good idea from many respects - cost being one of the problems.

Why don't you more completely describe what you are trying to do.  It's really hard for us to figure out what you are trying to accomplish, especially given the capacitor value that you mention.

Answer (score 2):

Your biggest problem is that you don't know what a virtual ground is, and you need one if you're going to power your op amp from a single 5 volt supply. Try

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0MfTz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

with the proviso that, depending on the input impedance of the next stage, you may have to increase the value of C4.

As it stands, your circuit is attempting to produce a negative output from a negative input, and it cannot do that since its negative supply is ground. Technically, your op amp is attempting half-wave rectification, except that it gets more complicated than that due to feedback.

EDIT - Error in R1 connection - fixed.

Also, from comments in the OP - Even if you get everything right, you cannot drive a 23 ohm load with your op amps. They will not provide the current required, and will produce a low output voltage. Just like you're getting.

Comment: But the reason I never did that this way was because I was under the assumption from some browsing on the subject that I needed a negative and a positive supply still for the initial op amp, which is a paradox of sorts

Comment: No, you need dual supplies to allow the output to go both positive and negative. Op amps aren't magic. They can only produce an output within the limits of their power supplies (although driving inductors can produce subsequent higher voltages, but this does not apply to your circuit). And if you were under the assumption that you needed a both a negative and positive supply, why didn't you provide them? How can the need for two supplies (or a single supply modified as I've shown) be a paradox? The negative op amp input does not necessarily have to be tied to ground.

Comment: Well for starters, I have nothing that can invert the voltage. I did order some TI parts, but they won't be here for a while. So as far as that goes, It looked as though both the MAX410 and 492 were able to be operated off a single supply (I actually called Maxim and a tech told me I could use +5V and GND). The paradox was referring to the fact that if I need dual supplies for what I'm currently using and can't provide that, then how am I supposed to provide dual supplies to another op amp to use as a buffer? One cannot be done without the other evidently.

Comment: Right. And that's when you use a virtual ground such as I provided in my schematic. And the fact that you are unwilling to provide a negative supply for op amp A does not imply the existence of a paradox when you cannot provide a negative supply for op amp B. "I can't do A: therefor I can't do B" is not a paradox.

Comment: You're confusing me. If the op amp I currently have cannot function supposedly without a negative supply, how is the buffer op amp supposed to function properly? Because everyone is claiming now that op amps can't work without a negative supply... well your schematic has the buffer op amp tied to GND... so I have all you guys saying one thing and the datasheet and Maxim saying another and no explanation.

Comment: Please. Pay attention to my statement "Op amps aren't magic. They can only produce an output within the limits of their power supplies". Of course op amps can work without a negative supply. What they cannot do with a single supply is produce an output (at the op amp) above the power supply voltage or below ground. However, if you provide an intermediate virtual ground (as my schematic did), and capacitively couple the inputs and outputs, you can accept negative inputs and produce negative outputs.

Comment: I am paying attention. Your statements just sound contradictory. But explain why a voltage divider won't work, please. That is what has been recommended by several sources.

Comment: Sorry. Since you don't understand capacitive coupling the discussion is at an end.

Comment: I do understand capacitive coupling. There you guys go again with the condescension. But what I'm trying to understand are op amps. What I'm looking to figure out is if all I need is a VOLTAGE (not current) source at 1\2 that of my input voltage, then why go to all this trouble if a voltage divider will provide that half source? Seriously? You are one of two people that has recommended your method over a voltage divider. So explain WHY, or explain WHY NOT. What is the benefit?

Comment: Ah. You noticed, I hope, that I DID use a divider. Am I correct that what you MEANT to ask is "Why a divider followed by a buffer, and not just a divider?"?   The answer is "effective impedance". The voltage out of a divider will vary depending on the other components connected to it which source or sink current. By putting a buffer on the output I provide a very low impedance at V/2, and this allows much easier analysis of what the circuit will do, and makes it much easier to get the desired output.

Comment: I did notice the divider before the buffer. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: I just put together your entire schematic and it still is the same volume

Comment: @DominicLuciano - see edit above.

Comment: Okay that edit fixed it. And I understand this op amp isn't going to work, so I'm getting a different one to use instead